# Dynamically resize Simple Modal Depending on what is clicked

Tags: jquery, simplemodal

I am fairly new to jQuery/JavaScript so I am having a few problems, hopefully you can point me on the right track.

On my project I have a row of images, showing previews of images. Kind of a image gallery.

I want to be able to click onto the smaller images and then get simple Modal to display the full size image, dynamically resizing and animating.

Can I do this with Ajax, to refresh simple modal? I am still learning how to use Ajax with jQuery and there seems many ways to do it.

Here is what I have:

jQuery:

```
$('.col1').find('img.overlay').click(function() {

                $('#imgpreview').modal({overlayClose:true});

                var img = $(this).parent().find('img.shared').attr('src');
                var imgW = $(this).parent().find('img.shared').attr('width');
                var imgH = $(this).parent().find('img.shared').attr('height');

                $('#imgpreview').css('width', imgW);
                $('#imgpreview').css('height', imgH);                   
                $('#imgpreview').find('img').attr('src', img);

            });

    });
```

HTML:

```
            <div id="imgpreview"><img src=""></div>
                        <div class="col1 bg"><img class="overlay" src="img/overlay.gif" width="104" height="104"><img class="shared" width="104" height="104" src="img/uploaded/img1.jpg"></div>
                        <div class="col1 bg"><img class="overlay" src="img/overlay.gif" width="104" height="104"><img class="shared" width="104" height="104" src="img/uploaded/img2.jpg"></div>
                        <div class="col1 bg"><img class="overlay" src="img/overlay.gif" width="104" height="104"><img class="shared" width="104" height="104" src="img/uploaded/img3.jpg"></div>
                        <div class="col1 bg"><img class="overlay" src="img/overlay.gif" width="104" height="104"><img class="shared" width="104" height="104" src="img/uploaded/img4.png"></div>
                        <div class="col1 bg"><img class="overlay" src="img/overlay.gif" width="104" height="104"><img class="shared" width="104" height="104" src="img/uploaded/img5.jpg"></div>
                        <div class="col1 bg nmr"><img class="overlay" src="img/overlay.gif" width="104" height="104"><img class="shared" width="104" src="img/uploaded/img6.jpg"></div>
```

I can display the image inside the simple modal but the image does not sit inside the dimensions of the image so I can give it a border and styling, also means it does not sit in the middle.

Another option is to create a simple modal dialogue box for each image and echo out the jQuery with PHP since the images will be in the database. But would there be a better way?

Comment: html please, nm about the modal bit.

Comment: Added the HTML to the question.

Comment: first off, you are using your original size elements as your "big picture" size dimensions.  Ofcourse this will not have the correct dimensions.  I don't know anything about "modal" but I've found jQuery plugins usually aren't worth the trouble of rolling your own solutions.  I would throw the "big picture" in a div tag so you could move it and do whatever you wanted to.  Let me whip up a solution if that ain't clear.

Comment: Thanks Dale. I have resized one of the images to 104x104 and at a later time I was going to get the dimensions of the big picture from the DB.

Yeah this plugin is becomming a bit fiddly haha. I think perhaps doing it myself could be worthwhile. Simple modal has a nice feature that blacks out the rest of the page but I guess I can do this manually myself. Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a clue about that modal plugin.  It's been my experience that jQuery plugins are hardly worth the trouble of figuring out.  That being said, you could try this....

```
<head>
    $(document).ready( function() {
        $('.overlay).click( function() {
            $('#bigPic).append('<img id="myPic" src="my dynamic source.gif"/>');
        });//end click
    });//end ready
</head>

<body>
    <div id="previews">

        //Your posted html here
    </div>
    <div id="bigPic">

    </div>
</body>
```

Then the CSS would have something like :
    img #myPic{
         height: 100%;
         width: 100%;
    }

It looks like you are a little confused by what this is in your question.  In your case it is $("img.overlay")  You can avoid all that nonsense by just adjusting the

```
<div id="bigPic">
```

to suit your needs.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think Douglas Crockford says the location of the $(document).ready() here is in the totally inappropriate location.  I dont know, I don't understand half of what that guy is talking about, but he is definately someone worth listening to.  Cheers to you too, happy coding!